# Coordinate transformation: Spherical to Cartesian

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I'd like to calculate the x, y, z distance to an object given its spherical coordinates theta and phi and it's altitude above the earth. My origin is on the surface of the earth so I don't know the rho coordinate of the object.

I think I can do that using the x, y, z formulas listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) but I am not sure how to calculate the distance that the object is from me (rho).  How should I approach this?  I'd like to assume the earth is a simple sphere for this exercise.

I took a look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/spherical-coordinates.html) MATLAB page and it mentions a "broadside" formula but I am not sure how my angles line up with the angles that it mentions.

Example:
Altitude = 100
Theta = 30deg
Phi = 30deg

I've thought about trying to make a triangle with one side being radius of the earth, the second side being radius of earth + altitude and the third side being rho.  I am not sure how to calculate the angles of that triangle.

Comment: If the object's speherical coordinates are $\;(\rho,\,\theta,\,\phi)\;$ , its distance from the origin is simply $\;\rho\;$ ...

Comment: True, but all I know about the object is it's altitude above the earth. I don't know ρ so I need to calculate it.  I have my origin on the surface of the earth

Comment: By "altitude", you mean its height over the $\;xy\,-$ plane, or what?

Comment: I mean altitude above the surface of the earth

Comment: If you assume that the earth is a sphere, $\rho$ is simply the radius of this sphere plus the altitude.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I have the origin at the surface of the earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

You can calculate rho by considering a triangle:
The central angle would be 180 - theta and the two sides would have length of radius of the earth and radius of the earth + altitude.  The third side can be figured out with the law of sines.

Once you have rho, you can calculate x, y, z based on how the the spherical coordinate system is specified (directions of +x, +y, +z).

Answer (score 0):

Steps for a "naive" way.

1. Given any two points $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r'$, the distance between them is $d(\mathbf r, \mathbf r') = \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2}$.
2. Determine the cartesian components $x,y,z$ and $x',y',z'$ for both points from the spherical coordinates you currently have.
3. Plug the expressions from the last step into the formula in the first step.

To deal with the altitude, notice that your position is just $\mathbf r = (R + h)\hat{\boldsymbol \rho}$ where $\hat{\boldsymbol \rho}$ is the radially outward-point unit vector $R$ is the radius of the Earth, and $h$ is your height above the surface, and there are standard expressions for that unit vector that you can look up.

Comment: Exactly: I don't have x', y', z' and x, y, z = 0.  My origin is on the surface of the earth.

Comment: Does the last paragraph alleviate your concern?

Comment: No since I am trying to figure out how far the object is from my origin.  I know how far the object is from the center of the earth but my origin is on the surface of the earth

Comment: Sure, but notice the following.  The point on the surface has coordinates relative to the center of the Earth.  The point that you want to find the distance to also has coordinates relative to the center of the Earth.  Now simply apply the algorithm I gave in the answer to those coordinates.  Since distance is independent of choice of origin, you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Can you do the calculations using the example I provided? (Altitude, Theta, Phi?)

Comment: No because that would be giving away the answer, and where would be the learning and/or fun in that?